Archimate relations types and possible subtypes
In Archimate standart we can describe different entities in enterprise architecture as elements like Product, Capability, Application, Device and etc.
And having an element Application we can have different representatives of IT landscape: CRM systems, billing and others.
Vut when we come to relations there is no such subdivision. For example, composition is always a composition.
But can we subdivide relations into some subtypes?
For example we have CRM application and employees John Doe and Jim Smith. John is a Producvt Owner and Jim ias a tech lead.
How can I describe that Actor element is assigned to Application element with saving information that an assignment can be as a PO or Techlead?
Is thisa general relation called assignment having an attribure called a role or can I divide Assignment relation into two or more types?
I tried reading Archimate specs but did not found direct answer
